# How to search a MySQL blob column for a partial hex string?

Tags: mysql, sql, blob, mysql-workbench

I would like to SELECT a table row by searching a Blob's hex string value. I have a blob value that I want to find whose hex representation is 0041b074351bfa1092fd740c146f26ae. I would like to able to SELECT for this row by typing all or part of the string. Is this possible?

Comment: Might say something stupid but did you simply tried a SELECT FROM your_table WHERE blob LIKE '%value%' ?

Comment: Yes. The data is stored as raw bytes, but I want MySQL to cast those bytes to a hex string and then do a search such as LIKE %value%. If you enter "SELECT FROM your_table WHERE (transactionId LIKE %0041b074351bfa1092fd740c146f26ae%)" does not work.

Comment: Mind the performance issues that this approach has. If disk space is not a concern, I would create an additional column to store the hex representation of each blob, provided that read queries significantly outnumber write queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1
WHERE UNHEX(hex_col) LIKE '%value%';
```

ps: It can be really slow when comes to performance. Be careful. 
;-)

Answer (score 0):

Simple query is working fine for me.. Please try like this

**EG.**

SELECT *

FROM **YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE**

WHERE **YOUR_BLOB_FIELD_NAME_HERE** LIKE '%**SEARCH_TEXT_HERE**%'